# ASP pagination for beginners

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, pagination

I'm creating a TV guide in ASP (Classic ASP), and although I can do a PHP one well enough, the PC I'm on has IIS as its web server, with MySQL. It's a shared PC for educational use and web development, and users are encouraged to develop test sites.
Although IIS is running, with ASP.NET, *.asp was set as an ISAPI filter

I'm trying to emulate the ASP seen at http://library.digiguide.tv/lib/programmenextshowing/12578&hPage=3 and http://library.digiguide.tv/lib/programmenextshowing/12578 for my ASP pagination - plus a few simple page templates in ASP.

My .NET framework version is 4.0.

How can I do this for a beginner? I had a look on Google, but couldn't find much that would work with Windows 7.

(Forgot to mention, the computer only has MySQL as its database driver on it, the latest one, so MDB isn't possible)

Cheers

JC

Answer (score 1):

As you've stated this is for educational purposes, the best thing for you is to read a beginners guide online, as you've posted a far too broad question to be answered in a single response.

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs

When you have a specific code-related question do come back and post, along with relevant code, so you can get a specific answer to a specific question.

Good luck.